# Do you include the concrete that squeezes out under the frame as part of the depth of the concrete driveway?

Tags: concrete

We had professional concrete contractors pour a new driveway.  We asked for five inches depth.  When I measured at the side of the driveway I found concrete had squeezed out under the frame.  Do you measure the squeezed out portion as part of the driveway depth?  Please help!

Answer (score 2):

You would measure the thickness, from the base to the top of the form. If the form was an inch off the ground that extra inch is part of your new slab. It just dosenot look as nice unless putting a lawn next to the slab. I have done things like this but usually back fill because the concrete that gets out is a waste of $.

Comment: +1 for acknowledging “true” depth is what you’re measuring, not appearance.